# How can we get the domain of $F(x) = \int f(x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, improper-integrals

Let $$F(x) = \int f(x) dx.$$ My question is how can we get the domain of F(x) generally. I usually think in f(x), and I imagine where it makes sense to take the area under the curve, but I'm afraid this method is not very trustworthy.
To illustrate my reasoning:

If $$ h(x) =  \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\log(1-t^{2})+t^{2}}{t}dt \ $$ I think first in f(x) = $[log(1-t^{2})+t^{2}]/t$ and where it would make sense to take the area aka its domain. As f(x) domain is (-1,1)\ {0} I get to conclusion that it only makes sense to take the area under the curve on this same interval therefore $D_{F}$ = (-1,1)\ {0}.

Thoughts on this? Is there a more efficient way of getting the domain of F(x) that I'm not aware of? Any help is welcome.

Comment: The antiderivative still converges near $0$ by squeeze theorem. In general the domain of the integrand is always a subset of the domain of the antiderivative.

Comment: @NinadMunshi could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Your question reduces to identifying when the computation $\int_a^b f(t)dt$ is meaningful, where $F'(t) = f(t)$.  First of all, it is understood that if $F$ is well defined on the interval $[a,b]$, then the computation is **automatically** meaningful.  Therefore, the question is what happens when you have an improper integral.  As an example, suppose that $F(t)$ happens to be well defined on $(a,b]$ but is **not** defined at $(t=a)$.  Then, you examine the $\lim_{c \to a^+} \int_c^b f(t)dt = F(b) - F(c).$  ...see next comment

Comment: That is, the issue will be, in this case, when $c$ approaches $a$ from **above**, does the limit exist.  More formally does $\lim_{c \to a^+} F(c)$ exist.  If it does, then the integral has a meaningful value.  If the limit does not exist, then the integral can not be computed.

Comment: Just so there is no misunderstanding, if the previous question is altered so that $F$ is well defined on [a,b] except at $(t = d)$, where $a < d < b$ then, to compute the improper integral $\int_a^b f(t)dt,$ you have to **attempt** to compute $\lim_{e\to d^-} \int_a^e f(t)dt$ and $\lim_{h\to d^+} \int_h^b f(t)dt$ **separately**.  If **either** limit fails to exist, then you **can not** compute $\int_a^b f(t)dt.$

Comment: @NinadMunshi "In general the domain of the integrand is always a subset of the domain of the antiderivative."  Are you sure?  This seems to conflict with the comments that I have just made.  Do you disagree with my comments?

Comment: @user2661923 How does the integral have a meaningful value if the limit exists? What's the relation?

Comment: @arpg For background, please re-read the first comment that I wrote, following the query.  In that example, assuming that the following limit exists, $$\int_a^b f(t)dt = \lim_{c \to a^+} \int_c^b f(t)dt = F(b) - \left[\lim_{c \to a^+} F(c)\right].$$

Comment: Yes but my point is just because $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists it doesn't imply that f(a) exists, correct?

Comment: If you mean that just because $\lim_{x \to a^+} F(x)$ exists does not imply that $F(a)$ exists, I completely agree.  The whole point of my analysis is that **when** (for example) $F(a)$ does **not** exist, you have an **improper** integral, and therefore must consider **whether** the following limit exists: $\lim_{x \to a^+} F(x)$.